# LISP compare an Element in a Board

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I'm doing a project for college in Common Lisp

And I need to compare a 4x4 list
Example:

```
(
((white full circle) (black empty circle) (black full circle) (white empty circle))
(0 0 0 0)
(0 0 0 0)
(0 0 0 0)
)
```

I need to compare if a line have 4 lists that share an element, in this case "circle"
and I can't use any defvar like intersection, need to use it recursively, and I can't find a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun find-common (x)
  (labels ((compare (items lst)
            (cond ((null items) nil)
              ((not (remove-if #'(lambda (k) (member (car items) k)) lst))
               (cons (car items) (compare (cdr items) lst)))
              (t (compare (cdr items) lst)))))
    (cond ((null x) nil)
      (t (cons (compare (caar x) (car x)) 
               (find-common (cdr x)))))))
```

To see if a list of list shares a common element, we have to check if each element in the `car` of that list also occurs in each list of its `cdr`. That's what the `compare` function does. It checks if an element occurs in all the lists recursively.

The `find-common` function recursively searches for all common occurrences in the list of lists.

Let's assume `table` is your 4 x 4 list:

```
(setf table
    '(((white full circle) (black empty circle) (black full circle) (white empty circle))
      ((3 2 8 5) (2 9 1 8) (23 8 2 1) (3 8 0 2))
      ((one five six) (six one five) (five one six) (one six five))
      ((green blue red) (green red blue) (silver red white) (green yellow blue))))
```

Calling the `find-common` function:

```
>(find-common table)

((CIRCLE) (2 8) (ONE FIVE SIX) NIL)
```

Comment: Don't use `defun` in a function body.  It does not do what you think it does.  It will define a top level function.  Use `flet` or `labels` to define local functions.  Also, please use proper indentation and code formatting.

Comment: @Svante, Thanks. Edited the answer accordingly.